# how can show file from folder to fileUploader in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i wanna load file from directory(Content/files) to fileuploader when i click on Edit button.
i mean for example standard15.pdf will show in   @Html.TextBoxFor(z => z.fileEstandard)   and i can change it .

my class :

```
 public class estandardclass
  {

    public long id { get; set; }


    public string namefile { get; set; }


    public HttpPostedFileBase fileEstandard { get; set; }


    public string attachfile { get; set; }


      }
```

my view :

```
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">select standard file  </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(z => z.fileEstandard, new { @type = "file", name = "fileEstandard[0]"  })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(z => z.fileEstandard)
    </div>
```

my controller :

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditStandard(long idd)
    {
        var db = new myprojectContext();
        estandardclass estanclass = new estandardclass();
        var tbl = adminclass.getSpeseficDownload(idd).FirstOrDefault();


         // what should i do here


        return View();

    }
```

Comment: what do u mean by loading pdf file inside file upload control ,

Comment: i want to edit the file that user selected before.i should load that file in file Upload Control , is not it?

Comment: u mean , u want to allow user to edit your pdf file right ?

Comment: yes , user can change file that selected before

Answer (score 0):

there are not many options you have to fill your strange requirements,

first what you can do is parse PDF on server side and Render its content inside some wysiwyg editor , which then user can edit and save it back , also there are plugins for wysiwyg editors like fckeditor or tinymce which does provide export to pdf which you can manually call on save

second [RAD PDF](http://www.radpdf.com/demo/) which provides document editing on client side , its not open source so you have to buy it..